# CSS Hover animation in reverse, Animation Challenge

Tags: css

I found a hover animation that I really like and I've been trying to recreate it as a bit of a challenge to myself.

Animation can be found here: https://thisisgala.co.uk/

It's the Latest / About / Sustainability Links about halfway down the page.

Using the browser inspector to inspect their code, I've been able to copy animation times and transform properties etc, and I've been able to replicate the effect with some success, however I cannot get mine to animate in reverse when the mouse leaves the link.

[I've created a codepen here](https://codepen.io/alexhoggett/pen/dyQBJoP?editors=1100)

Additionally, Something just does not feel as satisfying with mine and I'm open to any suggestions to achieve the desired animation.

```css
.link {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: -.6px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
  -moz-perspective: 100px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.link:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Topside */

.transition {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}

.text__normal {
  visibility: visible;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.text__normal span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(25px);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.link:hover .text__normal>span {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(25px) translateX(20px);
}


/* Flipside */

.text__flip {
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition-delay: 100ms;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.text__flip span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(25px);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}

.link:hover .text__flip span {
  transition-delay: 100ms;
}

.link:hover .text__flip>span {
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(25px) translateX(20px);
}


/* Delays */

.link:hover .char1 {
  transition-delay: 15ms;
}

.link:hover .char2 {
  transition-delay: 30ms;
}

.link:hover .char3 {
  transition-delay: 45ms;
}

.link:hover .char4 {
  transition-delay: 60ms;
}


/* For testing */

.link:hover .char5 {
  transition-delay: 75ms;
}

.link:hover .char6 {
  transition-delay: 115ms;
}

.link:hover .char7 {
  transition-delay: 130ms;
}

.link:hover .char8 {
  transition-delay: 145ms;
}

.link:hover .char9 {
  transition-delay: 160ms;
}

.link:hover .char10 {
  transition-delay: 175ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="link">
    <span class="transition">
      <span class="text__normal transition">
        <span class="char1">A</span>
        <span class="char2">n</span>
        <span class="char3">i</span>
        <span class="char4">m</span>
        <span class="char5">a</span>
        <span class="char6">t</span>
        <span class="char7">e</span>
        <span class="char8">d</span>
      </span>
      <span class="text__flip transition">
        <span class="char1">A</span>
        <span class="char2">n</span>
        <span class="char3">i</span>
        <span class="char4">m</span>
        <span class="char5">a</span>
        <span class="char6">t</span>
        <span class="char7">e</span>
        <span class="char8">d</span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below hope this will help to you.

```css
.quickLinksOuter .quickLink .text {
        display: inline;
        position: relative
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink .text .textNormal {
        visibility: visible;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        position: relative
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink .text .textNormal span {
        display: inline-block;
        transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(25px);
        transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
        backface-visibility: hidden
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink .text .textFlip {
        visibility: visible;
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition-delay: 100ms
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink .text .textFlip span {
        display: inline-block;
        transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(25px);
        transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
        backface-visibility: hidden
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink .text span span {
        min-width: 8px
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink .text span span:nth-child(1) {
        transition-delay: 15ms
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink .text span span:nth-child(2) {
        transition-delay: 30ms
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink .text span span:nth-child(3) {
        transition-delay: 45ms
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink .text span span:nth-child(4) {
        transition-delay: 60ms
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink .text span span:nth-child(5) {
        transition-delay: 75ms
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink .text span span:nth-child(6) {
        transition-delay: 90ms
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink .text span span:nth-child(7) {
        transition-delay: 105ms
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink .text span span:nth-child(8) {
        transition-delay: 120ms
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink .text span span:nth-child(9) {
        transition-delay: 135ms
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink .text span span:nth-child(10) {
        transition-delay: 150ms
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink .text span span:nth-child(11) {
        transition-delay: 165ms
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink .text span span:nth-child(12) {
        transition-delay: 190ms
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink .text span span:nth-child(13) {
        transition-delay: 205ms
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink .text span span:nth-child(14) {
        transition-delay: 220ms
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink .text span span:nth-child(15) {
        transition-delay: 235ms
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink:hover .text .textNormal {
        margin-left: 0
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink:hover .text .textNormal span {
        transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(25px)
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink:hover .text .textFlip {
        Transform: translateX(10px)
    }

    .quickLinksOuter .quickLink:hover .text .textFlip span {
        transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(25px)
    }

   .quickLinksOuter {
            display: block
        }

        .quickLinksOuter .quickLinks {
            width: 83.333%;
            margin: 0 0 0 16.667%;
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 20px
        }

        .quickLinksOuter .quickLinks .quickLink {
            font-size: 40px;
            line-height: 40px;
            letter-spacing: -.8px;
            height: 50px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px
        }
```

```html
<div class="quickLinksOuter">
   <div class="quickLinks">
      <a href="https://thisisgala.co.uk/news/" class="quickLink colPad" data-id="1">
      <span class="text transition">
      <span class="textNormal transition">
          <span class="char1">A</span><span class="char2">n</span><span class="char3">i</span><span class="char4">m</span><span class="char5">a</span><span class="char6">t</span><span class="char7">e</span><span class="char8">d</span>
      </span>
      <span class="textFlip transition">
          <span class="char1">A</span><span class="char2">n</span><span class="char3">i</span><span class="char4">m</span><span class="char5">a</span><span class="char6">t</span><span class="char7">e</span><span class="char8">d</span>
        </span>
      </span>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```